# $\mathbb{R}^\ast$, $\mathbb{R}_+$, $\mathbb{R}^\ast_+$ "deprecated"?

Tags: notation, real-numbers

I have recently stumbled upon [this page in ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:R), which asserts that the notations
$$
\mathbb{R}^\ast = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{R}_+ = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x\geq 0\}
$$
are both "deprecated." Is there a reason for that? (these notations are the ones I'm familiar with, and the ones I learnt since middle school)

Comment: I use $\mathbb{R}^*$ or $\mathbb{R}^\times$ for the multiplicative group of the field $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, in my opinion this is not deprecated.

Comment: I don't see why these notations would be "deprecated" (by whom, anyway? There's no governance body for math notation). The only "problem" that could arise is whether $\mathbb{R}_+$ is $(0,+\infty)$ or $[0,+\infty)$ but often the context makes it clear. Ask them what they mean by that...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: There is such a body; it's called ISO. They have invented the ${\rm d}$ for $d$ and similar things. Sooner or later they will charge us for using the symbol $\pi$, since they have"authorized" it.

Comment: I'm not really sure I know what you're talking about. I know ISO sets some style norms for their own papers and the papers of the people who want to conform to ISO, but I doubt even 5% of mathematicians alive ever interacted with ISO or care what ISO thinks...

Comment: They also deprecate (because of "overuse")  $x\mid y$ in favor of $x\setminus y$ (while sticking with $x\nmid y$ for the negation) but are undecided about $A-B$ vs. $A\setminus B$. Go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're deprecated, they're deprecated **for ProofWiki**, certainly not in general.  Any particular forum or journal is free to choose their own standards for mathematical notation.  The main criterion should be to avoid confusion.  The problem with $\mathbb R_+$, I think, is that it may not be obvious whether you mean $\ge 0$ or $> 0$.  As for $\mathbb R^*$, perhaps it's that $^\star$ has many different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks... so, basically, it's an subjective, website-dependent "deprecation."

Answer (score 1):

There are still many people who use this notation. Still, I would recommend the following.

$\mathbb R^\times$ looks very much like $\mathbb R^\ast$, but makes it clear that you want the multiplicative ($\times$) elements of $\mathbb R$, i.e. $\mathbb R^\times = \mathbb R \backslash \{ 0 \}$, and not its dual $\mathbb R^\ast = \operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb R, \mathbb R) \cong \mathbb R$. In a more general situation, $R^\times$ (for any ring $R$) is used often for the set of units, and $R^\ast$ could mean "multiplicative elements" or "all elements except zero" or, again, the dual of $R$, i.e. $\operatorname{Hom} (R, R)$, thinking of $R$ as a module over itself.

$\mathbb R_+$ is less ambiguously written as either $\mathbb R_{>0}$ or $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. (Of course, paired with $\mathbb R_+^\ast$ the risk of confusion is not as great, since here $^\ast$ wouldn't mean the dual vector space, but then $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is equally easy to write and unambiguous.)